# Is it possible to run raspbian OS without SD card or Live USB?

Tags: python, raspbian, gui, ram, sd-card

I developed a python based GUI application running on a Raspbian OS. During power outage my SD card gets corrupted often. I need to have a frequent back up OS image and writing it back when the SD card gets corrupted. Is there any solution that my Raspbian OS able to run without SD card/Live USB?.

Comment: The big question is: After power outage, how should you App get into RAM then? From SDCard? See the problem?

Comment: yes you are correct. But i came across some Linux distributions like NARD SDK which can load the application in to RAM from SD card. While the application is running you can remove the SD card it seems providing you have no dependency on SD card for any data.

Comment: It's better the application can load into the ROM/FLASH of the controller instead of SD card. For initial booting of application only i need SD card after that my application should run from processor. Even after recycling the power it should run from processor memory instead of SD card.

Comment: But you have to get it into RAM first (power outage cleans RAM).If the SD ist somewhat corrupted, can the Pi boot then? The loading of the app into RAM is usually not the problem (in fact executing does exactly that). But the way HOW you get it into RAM is - also when using a RAM-Disk.

Comment: @vijayakumarsargunam Hello! Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/615606/edit) your question to add new information. This way other contributors will have a complete picture without looking through the comments. Comments get crowded quickly. Comments are better used to ask you for clarifications, so that you could improve your post.

Answer (score 2):

While it is easy to "run from RAM", this will not solve your problem.

The SD card will only get corrupted if you power off or **remove the card**, while also writing to the card.

Solutions:

- Stop writing to the card.
- Enable journaling on the file-system.
- Shutdown properly `shutdown -h now`.
- Reboot properly `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: And prevent power outage (USV or similar)

Answer (score 1):

For certain models of RPi it's possible to boot the RPi over network using DHCP/BOOTP and TFTP (and then very probably NFS). **This requires an other permanent system providing DHCP/BOOTP, TFTP and NFS services** since the RPi has nothing when it's booting. This can work only with Ethernet, not Wireless.

Documentation on how to do this for RPi 3B and even RPi 4 exist. I won't attempt to copy all the details here, because it's quite lengthy, please refer to the links below.

- [Official documentation for RPi3B and RPi3B+](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes)

  RPi3B (not RPi 3B+) must initially "blow a fuse" to enable network boot:

  > Before a Raspberry Pi will network boot, it needs to be booted from an
  > SD card with a config option to enable USB boot mode. This will set a
  > bit in the OTP (One Time Programmable) memory in the Raspberry Pi SoC
  > that **enables network booting**.

  Then it's all about configuring the other server to provided mandatory services for a proper network boot (this would be mostly similar to offering network boot to an other system than to a RPi).
- Here's an other documentation to do this, [where the permanent server is running CentOS instead of Raspberry OS](https://hackaday.com/2018/10/08/hack-my-house-running-raspberry-pi-without-an-sd-card/)
- [The same is possible for RPi4](https://hackaday.com/2019/11/11/network-booting-the-pi-4/); it involves possibly having to reflash the RPi4 to update the PXE boot code. Here's an excerpt (which must be updated in its various filenames):

  > ```
  > sudo apt-get update
  > sudo apt-get upgrade
  > wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/raw/master/firmware/beta/pieeprom-2019-10-16.bin
  > rpi-eeprom-config pieeprom-2019-10-16.bin > bootconf.txt
  > sed -i s/0x1/0x21/g bootconf.txt
  > rpi-eeprom-config --out pieeprom-2019-10-16-netboot.bin --config bootconf.txt pieeprom-2019-10-16.bin
  > sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f ./pieeprom-2019-10-16-netboot.bin
  > cat /proc/cpuinfo
  > ```

  and proceeds to again configuring the server (this time running Debian, so probably fine for Rasbpberry OS).